# Magento - show the stock indicator on product list

Tags: magento

how can I show the stock indicator on Magento product list ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What stck indicator are you refering to please?

Comment: It's the stock indicator of the etension "Market Ready Germany"
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/symmetrics+GmbH/extension/1764/market-ready-germany#overview

The stock indicator is visible by default in the product details and it uses a separate phtml template. Can I call it in the product list ?

Comment: You may want to provide more detail, since this is not a common extension. How is it loaded in the other layout? What parameters does it take? Clearly, the data exists and so it can be added in some way, but there's not enough detail here to see how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show the quantity of items left in stock use this:

```
<?php echo (int) Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); ?>
```

Comment: I'll work with this code to make my own stock indicator, thank.